# maven update in Eclipse: Could not update project

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, m2eclipse

I am doing first steps in REST with Jersey following [here](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/web-services/java-restful-web-services-tutorial-for-beginner-with-jersey-and-tomcat) using *m2e*.
It works fine deployed on tomcat 10.1, after a few adaptions to tomcat 10 and Java-17.

Now, I'd like to do a next step and put something new to the pom.xml. But doing *Maven / Update Project ...* leads to the failure message:

```
Could not update project HelloREST configuration
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.WorkbenchComponent.findResourcesByRuntimePath(org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath)"
because "aComponent" is null
```

Further, the Error Log also shows

```
eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=17.0.5
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender
Error
Tue Feb 07 13:19:45 CET 2023
HelloREST/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component is missing or invalid. Skipping module dependency configuration. Deployment issues may arise.
```

and

```
eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=17.0.5
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks
Error
Tue Feb 07 13:19:45 CET 2023
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.WorkbenchComponent.getProperties()" because "component" is null

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.WorkbenchComponent.getProperties()" because "component" is null
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualComponent.setMetaProperty(VirtualComponent.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.operation.ServerContextRootUpdateOperation.execute(ServerContextRootUpdateOperation.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2380)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.util.ComponentUtilities.setServerContextRoot(ComponentUtilities.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.project.J2EEProjectUtilities.setServerContextRoot(J2EEProjectUtilities.java:948)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WebProjectConfiguratorDelegate.configure(WebProjectConfiguratorDelegate.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.AbstractProjectConfiguratorDelegate.configureProject(AbstractProjectConfiguratorDelegate.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WTPProjectConfigurator.configure(WTPProjectConfigurator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$6(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$4(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.Collection.removeIf(Collection.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$3(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I do not see any other problem yet, but they may come. Any idea what could be the reason?

The failure messages does not disappear, when I try to reduce the project, even not if I delete .metadata and restart Eclipse.

The pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloREST</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>HelloREST</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>HelloREST</warName>
                    <outputDirectory>/opt/tomcat/webapps/</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Anything in the _Error Log_ view? If yes, please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: Hi, howlger. I edited: the failure is independent from the mentioned Server settings. The failure text above is a c'np from the Detailed view of the error message. Any other error log?

Comment: _Window > Show View > Error Log_ (or _... > Other...: Error Log_).

Comment: Please edit your question with this information (see my first comment). Did you install Eclipse 2022-12 from scratch or did you upgrade an existing installation to Eclipse 2022-12 (4.26)?

Comment: I am pretty sure I've installed Eclipse 2022-12 from scratch, although not 100% sure.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Please report it to [Web Tools Common](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools.common/developer) (since the top stack trace item happens [here](https://git.eclipse.org/r/plugins/gitiles/webtools-common/webtools.common/+/refs/heads/master/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore/modulecore-src/org/eclipse/wst/common/componentcore/internal/resources/VirtualComponent.java#279), even though a couple of components from different projects are also involved, e.g. m2e-wtp and m2e), with a minimal reproducible example and best with a patch.

Comment: Disagreeing with @howlger. It was triggered by a *Maven...Update Project*, and the entire tutorial is built around Maven, so m2e and m2e-wtp is where to start. Those are the components you are interacting with, and they're the ones who'll have to figure out whether they're doing something wrong or if it's really a problem in Web Tools Common. m2e-wtp depends on WTP, so you start with m2e-wtp.

Comment: What @nitind says. Please report it to [m2e-wtp](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-wtp/issues) (and not to  Web Tools Common) with a minimal reproducible example and best with a pull request. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following steps solved my problem:

1. Deleting the project from Eclipse Project Explorer, but not from the file system.
2. Deleting the *.settings* folder in the file system
3. Import the project again as *Existing Maven Project*

=====

I investigated a bit deeper. I found a reason with 2 file in the *.settings* folder:

1. *org.eclipse.wst.common.component*
2. *org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml*

The fist one was nearly empty. Just

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId"/>
```

The second contained a line

```
 <installed facet="jst.web" version="5.0"/>
```

Deleting that line and re-import the project replaced it by

```
<installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>
```

and filled the first file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="HelloREST">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="HelloREST"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/HelloREST/target/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

I have no clue about this, but two question are still unanswered (currently not very important to me):

- How did the *.settings* files got garbled?
- Why does *Eclipse Import Existing Maven Project* look at *.settings* files, while it works in the same way, when *.settings* files are deleted?

@nitind: From https://github.com/rolfschumacher/RoS-HelloREST.git you may *git clone* the erroneous project.

Comment: I tried out the above instructions on one of my projects, with a simplification. I just deleted the two files and then ran maven -> update. The aComponent issue is currently gone. Thanks for taking the time looking into this. I'll update if the issue comes back

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error in my before created SchoolManagement Project:
After searching more and more i got this as solution:

**There are two solution**

1- Update Maven (in project)

2- Delete Manually .setting folder from project --> again update maven in eclipse

Comment: Yes, Jitendra, deleting the *.settings* file works, but why?